# CH340G Uploading problem

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, ch340

I've tried to copy CH340G from other schematics and existing Arduino Uno Clones... 
Searched online & StackExchange but no good :/ My problem is almost the same as this one

Here is my schematic

[image: Schematics]

I can read & send data from the serial monitor

- OS: Win 10 64 Bit
- USB Driver: 3.5.2019.1

**Upload Options:**

- Arduino IDE version: 1.8.12
- Board: Arduino Uno (*also tired nano & nano old bootloader options*)

What I've tried:

- With & without the driver
- Rebooted the computer
- Tried different ports
- Different cables
- In case of IC not working, I've desoldered IC from working UNO
- Changed RX, TX vice versa
- Without R1 & R2
- Different capacitors on C6 and C3
  Buuut results are always the same as below

```
avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM3
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xf3
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xf3
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xf3
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xf3
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xf3
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xf3
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xf3
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xf3
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xf3
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xf3

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
```

I appreciate any help, idea, suggestion
Regards

Comment: Have you installed the bootloader?

Comment: Yes @Majenko, I've burned bootloader and uploaded code via ISP. I can communicate with it already, but can not upload code via USB

Comment: What else is on the RESET line?

Comment: If you can use the CH340 as a Serial-USB bridge (Serial.print and Serial.read work) but you cannot upload a sketch without using a programmer, the bootloader (or fuses) are bad for some reason.

Comment: @KIIV, 10k resistor like Uno and Nano (5V and reset signals)

Comment: @DataFiddler, How we're uploading program to Uno in your scenario? We're only hitting the upload button, not upload with the programmer. Can you explain this, please?

Comment: There is what you have to check: 1) toggling DTR should reset the MCU 2) check if the clock is running properly (upload blink sketch and check the frequency) - then reupload the bootloader

Comment: Btw, on newer arduino boards there is also fast diode between RESET and Vcc power rail to suppress voltage spike to 10V - as it might be enough to enter High voltage serial programming mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schematic is totally working. My mistake was after burning bootloader, I was uploading code via ISP. If you upload code via ISP, you're removing bootloader.

Thank you everyone who helped me to I wasn't mistaken at schematic and else...